# Vue.js: How do you change an icon and background color depending on the value of an item in a data table row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a data table with politicains. A politician can have a party value of either Democrat or Republican. If a politician is a Democrat, I want to show an mdi-donkey icon next to "Democrat" and I want the color of the row to change to blue. For Republicans, show an mdi-elephant icon and change to red. I believe I'm supposed to use v-bind, I tried to, and wasn't having much luck. Here's my working code:

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="politicians"
      :search="search"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  data(){
    return{
      search: '',
      headers: [
        {
          align: 'start'
        },
        {text: 'Position', value: 'position'},
        {text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
        {text: 'Party', value: 'party'}
      ],
      politicians: [
        {
            name: "John Smith",
            party: "Democrat",
            position: "County Executive"
        },
        {
            name: "Bob Bush",
            party: "Republican",
            position: "County Executive"
        },
        {
            name: "Elaina Krasinsky",
            party: "Democrat",
            position: "District Attorney"
        },
        {
            name: "Robert Parson",
            party: "Republican",
            position: "District Attorney"
        }
    ],
    }
  },
}
  
</script>

<style scoped>
    .Democrat{
      background-color: blue
    }
    .Republican {
       background-color: red
    }

</style>
```

I added styles for the background colors already. Can anyone get me on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `vuetify` so this should be possible. You can use slots to customize certain colums. This could be like this in your case:

```
<v-data-table
   :headers="headers"
   :items="politicians"
   :search="search"
>
   <template v-slot:item.party="{item}" :class="functionWhichSetsClass(item.party)">
      {{functionWhichShowsIcon(item.party)}}
   </template>
</v-data-table>
```

In this example you only customize the column for `party`. So you can change the additional content and how it looks.